# When shopping for ebooks on Amazon how do I tell if they have DRM?

Tags: amazon, drm

Some books sold on Amazon have DRM and some do not.  But "DRM" is not listed anyplace on the book descriptions that I have been able to find.  How can I know before I buy an ebook from Amazon if it has DRM?

Comment: This is because Amazon does not want to admit that drm is a problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Books that have "**Simultaneous Device Usage:** Unlimited" listed under "Product Details" do not have [DRM (Digital rights management)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management). Those without this disclaimer have DRM.

Comment: Is this still true? I can't find an ebook on Amazon with this product detail.

Comment: It is still true from my experience.  For example, when looking at books from Baen, you'll find that they do not have DRM, so all of those books should that Usage Unlimited tag.  Here is an example,  "Cats in Space" edited by Bill Fawcett.  

https://smile.amazon.com/Cats-Space-Other-Places-Fawcett-ebook/dp/B01M4M9FMP/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=Cats+in+Space&qid=1637524897&sr=8-2#detailBullets_feature_div