# How do I shop for only DRM free books on Amazon?

Tags: drm, amazon

I know [how to tell](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/285/when-shopping-for-ebooks-on-amazon-how-do-i-tell-if-they-have-drm) if a book on Amazon is DRM free.  There are lots of ways to sort, and filter books to just ones I am interested in on Amazon.  I want to also be able to limit to books that I would purchase, which for me means DRM free.

How can I add a filter or sort so when I am browsing Amazon I only see books that are DRM free?

Comment: Interestingly I see a drm-free option for video games, but not for ebooks.

Comment: wow you found a book on amazon without drm!

Comment: @hildred there will be many it is up to the publisher if you put DrM on. Several are DRM free e.g. Baen, TOR and no doubt several others

Comment: I wonder if looking for Simultaneous Device Usage: Unlimited in the details might work

Comment: @Mark No [Your search "Simultaneous Device Usage: Unlimited" did not match any products in: Kindle Store › Kindle eBooks](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=node%3D154606011&field-keywords=Simultaneous+Device+Usage%3A+Unlimited)

Comment: and I just bought a TOR book so no DrM and it did not have the Simultaneous Device Usage value on the web page

Comment: I don't know if there is still a way to search by tags, but there were many books tagged drmfree when tags were a main feature

Answer (score 10):

Since Amazon does not seem to let you search for this, you might want to use google:

```
site:www.amazon.com -forum "Simultaneous Device Usage: Unlimited" SEARCH-TERM
```

[Google for DRM-free thrillers](https://www.google.com/?q=site%3awww.amazon.com%20-forum%20%22Simultaneous%20Device%20Usage%3a%20Unlimited%22%20thriller)

Comment: +1 good answer. Though it does use an outside solution.  See [This answer](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/891) for an alternative. Calibre will also allow you search by a single retailer.

Comment: but not all DrM free books have this

Comment: @Mark . It is my understanding that all DRM-free Kindle ebooks on the Amazon store show "Unlimited" while the ones with DRM don't. Can you show an example where this is not the case?

Comment: @Hazzit The TOR book [Three Parts Dead](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Three-Parts-Dead-Craft-Sequence-ebook/dp/B0085UEQDO/ref=sr_1_1?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1392899489&sr=1-1&keywords=three+parts+dead) with comment "t the publisher's request, this title is being sold without Digital Rights Management software (DRM) applied." (Note I did not actually buy this copy to check from Amazon)

Comment: @Mark . Interesting find. I didn't spend $3 to get a definate answer, but please check this news item on cnet: http://news.cnet.com/8301-19882_3-10439335-250.html

Comment: @Hazzit - I think we need a detailed source for the command - the cnet article just says it is so and I thought so as per my comment to question of 20th Jan - but no official doc which is why I did not make it an answer

Answer (score 5):

Amazon does not currently have a method of displaying this information to the end user unfortunately. The author always has the option of informing his audience in the description, but that does not generally provide an easy way to identify the book as DRM-free via a search or filter.