# Are there any ebook search engines?

Tags: drm, search-engine, website

Are there any websites that work like ebook search engines, where you can perform a search over multiple stores and have the results sortable and/or filterable for file format, price, presence of DRM, and so on?

Comment: books.google.com?

Answer (score 22):

The one I use is [Luzme](http://luzme.com) It queries several stores including Kobo, Amazon, B&N and in several countries.

It then for each book shows the price that it last saw for each source and country.

It is searchable by book name and author and series, although the series data is not complete as it comes from the stores.

You can set up a wishlist of books and emails can be sent when they change price.

This site does provide DRM status if the store makes that data available.

The format is not shown however Amazon sites provide Kindle format and others at least ePub - I would be interested in any exceptions

Comment: Luzme does provide DRM status when known. For example, http://luzme.com/author/Andrew+Hunt/book/The+Pragmatic+Programmer+%3A+From+Journeyman+to+Master. The problem is that most sites don't show the DRM status, even when it should be DRM-free. (Disclaimer: Luzme is my site)

Answer (score 15):

Calibre is a [downloadable (free, donations accepted) application](http://calibre-ebook.com/) that will allow you to search over multiple stores, for content. Using the [get books](http://blog.calibre-ebook.com/2011/09/all-about-get-books.html) function, to provide information like comparative pricing between retailers and DRM status of the work at different retailers.

Answer (score 12):

Yes there are. The one I remember is [Inkmesh](http://inkmesh.com/).

You can filter by price, type (ebook, magazine, audiobook, etc.) device and language. Its database has large gaps though.

This site does not provide DRM status.

Answer (score 5):

There is a decent search engine called [Leatherbound ebook search engine](http://Leatherbound.me). Like Inkmesh and Luzme it allows you to search for a book across multiple stores and price compare. [Here](http://leatherbound.me/ebooks/NTt2lCj7Oz219m4z-Ghost_In_The_Wires__My_Adventures/) is a sample search result (for an entertaining book I might add).

In addition, you can search for printed books, free ebooks, ebook under $5 and some advanced search options.

This site does not provide DRM status.

Answer (score 5):

***Amazon only enhanced search engines*** (I'll group these together since they don't quite fit the question, but are still worth a mention).

---

[Jungle-Search](http://www.jungle-search.com/) is an interesting search engine. It's not limited to ebooks and is Amazon only (though you can choose from various Amazon stores, such as CAN/US/UK/GER/FRA). The purpose of this search engine is to allow you to more easily search by discount rates and price ranges.

[Here](http://www.jungle-search.com/US/#howto) is the how-to section (for US since most of our users are US; you can easily switch to another country at the top).

---

[eReaderIQ](http://www.ereaderiq.com/) allows you to search amazon, track books and add them to a watch list (being notified of price drops for books, authors etc.). It also has a history of pricing for ebooks. This is available for US/CAN/UK Amazon sites.

Comment: Why the two answers? You could just have edited your first one and extend it.

Comment: The test I ran on Jungle Search, seem to go straight to Amazon so DRM would be identified on their site.

Comment: On eReaderQ it looks like 'Lending: Enabled' = DRM free but I did not validate that assumption.

Comment: @Anthon: Because on many SE sites, questions that are asking for a site that does abc or a software program that does xyz people tend to complain when you put many answers in one (makes it harded to vote for good ones and down vote poor ones when they are mixed together). The only reason I grouped these two together is because they didn't were limited to Amazon only, which isn't quite what the question asked for. I figured people can downvote this one if they felt it wasn't fulfilling the requirements enough. My other answer hits more of the requirements and is probably a better choice.