# Where to find eBook designers?

Tags: kindle, mobi

I'm struggling to convert my book from InDesign to EBook / Kindle mobi format and I've tried finding somebody who could do it, but with no luck.

Does anybody know some online marketplace or somebody who is a pro in ebook design, so I could contact them and offer the job?

Comment: I work for a publishing company freelance and design their ebooks - maybe I could help: m.d.oroark@gmail.com

Comment: Get in touch and we can talk shop about the project / I can send you my resume / show you some of my portfolio

Comment: This is not a site for job announcements. Voted to close.

Comment: @Sekhemty why did you have to come and to do something like this? Don't you see that people are responding and that it really can help a lot of people?

Comment: @Sekhemty what's even more funny is that your own most popular question on here is of a very similar nature: http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/891/are-there-any-ebook-search-engines - shall we vote to close it too?

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is off-topic on this site; please consult the FAQS http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  This question is about finding someone to perform a job, not about solving a technical issue. It would have been OK if you just asked about how you can perform this task yourself, so if you want you can rewrite it to conform to the site policy. But in its current state it is just a job announcement, not a question related to ebooks as defined in the previously linked Help Center page

Comment: @Sekhemty well, your question linked above is also off-topic according to the FAQS because you're simply shopping for various search engines. but as you've seen it worked, because people found it useful. so why do you want to close my question, which can be useful to a lot of people, just because you personally think it's off topic? it is not – in fact, it's a huge problem - not being able to find the right ebook designer, so the question is asking for different ways to do that.

Comment: I think that we have a misunderstanding here. I don't WANT to close your question, and I don't PERSONALLY think that is is off topic; the site just have some rules. There are 4 close votes right now, this should prove that the question indeed has some issues. Please understand that this is not something personal. I'm sorry, but this question, in its current state, is not on topic. I have tried to explain to you why it is so, if you want you could try to improve it in order to conform to the site rules. As it is right now, I'm fairly sure that it will be closed.

Comment: Everyone, please keep in mind that the comments are not the place for extended discussion about what is on-topic. In fact, we have an entire site for that kind of discussion: [Ebooks Meta](http://meta.ebooks.stackexchange.com/). That is the right place for asking what is on-topic and debating whether question X should be closed and question Y left open. That said, @Sekhemty has correctly stated the reason that this post is off-topic.

Comment: @EdCottrell thank you, polizei! i just can't get my mind around the fact that some people are really willing to spend their time on commenting rather than just editing the question so that it would be more in the way the site is supposed to be...

Comment: @deemeetree I'm not sure how you meant the word "polizei," but you should know that it can be considered mildly offensive. As for your question, there's really no way for the community to edit it to make it on-topic. As you asked it, it is not about ebooks. There's no obvious way to turn it into a question about ebooks, instead of a job posting. That's why people commented on it and voted to close it.

Comment: Why offensive? "Polizei" is a word for "police" in Germany where I'm at. Is it offensive to call somebody "police"? Or you have a problem with the word "polizei"? And if so, should I be offended now?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Twitter, try reaching out to the #eprdctn hashtag—there are a number of ebook production professionals active there.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good list of reputable firms on Amazon's KDP page: https://kdp.amazon.com/help?topicId=A3RRQXI478DDG7