# Is there a way to share my Amazon eBook collection with other family members?

Tags: amazon, ebook-management

I have a decent sized collection of Amazon eBooks with a few titles that my family (siblings, parents) are interested in reading. Unfortunately, we all have our own Amazon accounts. Is there any way to share these eBooks?

We are all adults, so some sort of child sharing feature wouldn't be what we want. We don't have a problem with sharing being temporary or having a restriction where only one person can read the eBook at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can lend Kindle books to others through the Kindle store:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_rel_topic?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200549320

"A Kindle book can only be loaned one time" and loans are limited to 14 days.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything about it being one time for each borrower. Where is that?

Comment: @Thunderforge You're right. I was going partially by memory and partially by the statement directly below the video: "A Kindle book can only be loaned one time." That could well mean that once you have loaned a particular book, you can never loan it again. Which would be a pity, because this is the only mechanism available for loaning DRMed Kindle books to other Kindle users. This might also be helpful: http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/678/how-do-i-shop-for-only-drm-free-books-on-amazon

Answer (score 0):

On Amazon, there is also a family sharing account, but the restrictions are pretty big:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=help_search_1-2?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201733400&qid=1482462412&sr=1-2

One idea is to buy a cheap device under the primary account and then just share the device....

Another idea is to see if you can buy the ebook from a bookstore that lets you download the epub file directly.