# How Does Amazon Kindle Renting work on *buntu/Linux Systems?

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers, calibre, amazon, linux

I'm interested in renting this textbook ([https://www.amazon.com/Legal-Ethical-Issues-Nursing-Guido/dp/013335587X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013335587X)) from Amazon, but I am running a Linux system (Kubuntu 18.04.01).

How does renting from the Amazon store work if I'm running such a system? Do I need a special application to rent from the Amazon store, or will a program such a Calibre suffice?

Comment: Welcome to ebooks-SE.  Note that you can usually use shorter URL. For example, for the above book, this should be enough: http://amazon.com/Legal-Ethical-Issues-Nursing-Guido/dp/013335587X  . Are you sure this books exists for Kindle ... I cannot see it from my country, only the paper version. Last point is I never managed cleanly Kindle ebooks on Linux. Amazon is NOT Linux friendly. See for example https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6786/  You may try installing the Windows Kindle app with Wine.

Comment: What do you mean by renting? Which amazon product allows that. When I go to the url I see no option to rent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps renting works differently from buying/lending/borrowing ebooks, but all you do is to download the Kindle reading app on your device. Then, the rented item will magically appear after you purchase it.  I know the android Kindle app works great on mobile devices.

I don't know if Calibre has the ability to strip DRM from ebooks.(NOTE: We don't discuss DRM on this Stack Exchange). But the [Kindle cloud reader](https://read.amazon.com/) is browser-based, so I don't see why you can't just read ebooks in a web browser.